# Can't access a modified attribute from another screen class

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I create a simple app with Python and KivyMD. When the app running, the login screen asks for input. It was something like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen

class Login(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(login,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       self.user=""
       self.username=self.ids.usernamebox.text
       self.password=self.ids.passwordbox.text

    def checkusername(self)
         if self.username=="something" and self.password=="something":
              self.user="admin"
         else:
              self.user="member"
         sm.current='nextscreen'

class NextScreen(Screen):

   def somefeatures(self):
       if Login.user="admin":
           print(Login.user)
           pass
       if Login.user="member":
           print(Login.user)
           pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        global sm
        sm=ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Logon(name='login'))
        sm.add_widget(NextScreen(name='nextscreen'))
```

also, the kivy code if it any helps:

```
<Login>
   MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDTextField:
            id: usernamebox
            hint_text: "Username"

        MDTextField:
            id: passwordbox
            hint_text: "Password"

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            id: login
            text: "Login"
            on_release: root.checkusername()
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
<NextScreen>
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDFlatButton:
           text: "test"
           on_press: root.somefeatures()
```

I'm using kivy screen manager to switch between the classes.

What I try to achieve is how to make `somefeatures` prints the correct value of user after the user logged in

So far I've tried:

1. initializing the login class `l=login()` and access with `l.user`, didn't work because `__init__` returns 'user' as empty string
2. create `global user`, but still empty string
3. create `setuser` and `getuser` method within class login, but still can't return the value
4. initializing user outside the class `user=""` before any other classes, also empty string
5. Accessing the value of login class like the code above, it says `type object Login has no attribute user`

Is there is a way to achieve this? I want the value of user is still remembered as long as the app running (or until I make logout button, idk)

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you attach a **minimal** working example?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I ask you to attach a code that can be run without any manipulation, as well as without unnecessary functions and lines

Comment: I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

**this is main.py**

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
Builder.load_file('the.kv')

class fscreen(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        theapp.user = ''

    def checkusername(self):
            
        self.username = self.ids.password.text
        self.password = self.ids.username.text
        if self.username == "something" and self.password == "something":
            theapp.user = "admin"
            
        else:
            theapp.user = "member"


        print(self.username, self.password, theapp.user)
        theapp.screenm.current = "second screen"

        theapp.secscreen.userlabel = 'welcome   ' + theapp.user 

class secscreen(Widget):
    userlabel = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.userlabel = '' 
   

class thscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        supper().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screenm = ScreenManager()

        self.fscreen = fscreen()
        screen = Screen(name = "first screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.fscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)

        self.secscreen = secscreen()
        screen  = Screen(name = "second screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.secscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screenm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theapp = theapp()
    theapp.run()
```

**the.kv file**

```
<fscreen>

    TextInput:
        size: root.width*0.2, root.height*0.1
        pos: root.width*0.45, root.height*0.5
        id: username
        hint_text: 'username'

    TextInput:
        size: root.width*0.2, root.height*0.1
        pos: root.width*0.45, root.height*0.4
        id: password
        hint_text: 'password'

    Button:
        size: root.width*0.2, root.height*0.1
        pos: root.width*0.45, root.height*0.1
        text: 'login or something'
        on_press: root.checkusername()

<secscreen>
    Label:
        text: root.userlabel
        size: root.width*0.2, root.height*0.1
        pos: root.width*0.45, root.height*0.4
```

*ur problem was a class related,  u should read more about python classes.*

[image: fscreen]

[image: secscreen]

Comment: I've tried this before, it says the fscreen has no attribute user.